# NSE API returns NULL values for every API

Tags: php, api, php-curl

We need to implement option change. Following API  we are using:

```
https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=<--symbol-->
https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=<--symbol-->
```

By using CURL we are fetching the data from the API. When we are using the API at localserver it works correctly.
But, when the same file uploaded on main server; it returns an empty result.

Please check and give proper suggestion.

My code:

```php
$curl_handle = curl_init();
    
 - $request_headers = array(
       'Connection: keep-alive',
       'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
       'DNT: 1',
       'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
       'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79
   Safari/537.36',
       'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
       'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
       'Sec-Fetch-Site: none',
       'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
       'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8' );
   
   // Set the curl URL option curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,
   $url);
   
   // This option will return data as a string instead of direct output
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
   
   curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
   
   // Execute curl & store data in a variable $curl_data =
   curl_exec($curl_handle);

   
$response_data = json_decode($curl_data, true);
```

Comment: Does [`curl_error()`](https://php.net/curl_error) provide more informations?

Comment: What http status code do you get in the response? Could it be that the server has been blocked to make requests to that API? Have you also checked the web servers error log to see if there's any clues in there? You need to do some more debugging.

Comment: The code works correctly in localhost; but not working after uploading on server.